fetching the currenct financilal year data matching with previous year data by email,pan and mobile
I have more than 1,000,000 data rows in one table (example table name is :test1) and running below query and its taking more than 10 seconds to load the data so can you any one plz guide us to improve the load speed or any temp table can create and use it?
My Query
select distinct(email),'Prev Year Exist' as status 
from test1 
where created_date>='2024-04-01' and created_date<='2025-03-31'
AND ((pan in (select pan from test1 where created_date>='2023-04-01' and created_date<='2024-03-31'))
OR (mobileno in (select mobileno from test1 where created_date>='2023-04-01' and created_date<='2024-03-31'))
OR (email in (select email from test1 where created_date>='2023-04-01' and created_date<='2024-03-31')));

===============================================
its very slow to load the data so it should load faster using my query

Please publish the output from show create table test1; and an explain for the query

You can create an "explain" for a query by simply putting "EXPLAIN " in front of the query, see: EXPLAIN. It would also be useful to see the schema of the table and its indexes. Currently the query makes very little sense, this can certainly be rewritten to be more efficient. You basically have 4 queries when you only need 1. Please explain what the query is trying to achieve.

You don't need to create multiple subqueries, in your case, a simple join makes a lot more sense since all the subqueries have the same condition. I would go with the query below
SELECT DISTINCT t1.email, 'Prev Year Exist' AS status
FROM test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test1 t2 ON (
    (t1.pan = t2.pan OR t1.mobileno = t2.mobileno OR t1.email = t2.email)
    AND t2.created_date >= '2023-04-01' AND t2.created_date <= '2024-03-31'
)
WHERE t1.created_date >= '2024-04-01' 
  AND t1.created_date <= '2025-03-31'
  AND t2.email IS NOT NULL;

Also for more efficiency you can create an index on the created_date column as well

Hi, Amirreza Karimyrad.
Thanks for your replay and this code is not working for in the big data center plz help if you more than tha i nee how to create temp table use the my above code

I don't understand, can you share the output of my query and what did you expect it to be? do you mean you want to store the output of this query in a temporary table? something like a view?
